# How to generate apk file of a project which has a built in database in android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a project in android studio. Now i want to build an apk file of this project with the bulit in sqlite database.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the built in database (pre-loaded/pre-existing database) in the assets folder, and that you have implemented the code to access the database (generally this is a means of copying the database from the assets folder to a usable location).

Then you simply produce the APK no differently to building any other APK.

In short the database is just an asset and thus forms part of the package.